# Função "repita ... até <cond.>" em Python

Tags: python, pseudocódigo

Queria saber se existe a seguinte função, escrita em pseudocódigo, na linguagem Python:

**repita**
(comandos)

**até** (condição);

Obrigado.

Comment: Python só tem laços de dois formatos: **enquanto** e **para cada**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar um `while` assim:

```
contador = 0
while (contador < 9):
   print ('O contador é:', contador)
   contador = contador + 1
```

Dessa maneira ele verifica se a condição `contador < 9` ainda é válida e executa o interior do `while` caso seja verdadeira.

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/1q7ruO

Se quiseres fazer ao estilo `do`/`while` (fazer uma ação e verificar no final) podias fazer assim:

```
contador = 0
while True:
    print ('O contador é:', contador)
    contador = contador + 1
    if not contador < 9:
        break
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/8nJM2f